# How do I make a private repository that can still access updates from a public repository?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I'm working on a thesis project and I'll be extending a platform that was developed by researchers at another university. They're hosting the code of their platform on Github in a **public** repository.

My code isn't ready for publication yet. I want to use a **private** repository (for all the usual version control/remote backup in case of hardware failure reasons). If the thesis is successful I may want to make it public.

However, I would also like to be able to receive any updates from the original repository. At first I thought I would achieve this by forking the repo, but then discovered that forks of public repositories on Github are automatically public too.

I looked at the help given on [Github](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository) but I don't really understand if this will do what I need it to do. It gives a recipe but I don't really understand what it does or why it will/won't achieve my goals.

In summary:

- I want a private repository
- I would like to be able to get updates if anything new is added to the original public repository.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a server of your own ... say, with ssh, set up git there (installing the binary), create a bare repo on it and then add it as a remote of your local repo of the computer that you normaly work on... you can push then to your repo on *your* server when you feel like.

Comment: I meant private in the sense that Github repo can be private. Not as in "set up your own server" private.